# Tcl_SetObjLength: negative length requested error

Tags: debugging, scripting, tcl, file-handling

I have a file with roughly 42 million lines that I am trying to read and parse in TCL. However I get the below error message right after it prints D1. Are there any other alternatives to read large files?

```
proc test {} {
        set rpt "<file_name>"
        puts "D0"
        set lines [open $rpt r]
        puts "D1"
        set Data [read $lines]
        puts "D2"
        close $lines
}
```

**Output Error:**

```
D0
D1
Tcl_SetObjLength: negative length requested: -2147483646 (integer overflow?)
```

Comment: Ah yes, the 2GB limit for an individual memory object. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set fp [open inputfile r]
# Read one line at a time
while {[gets $fp line]!=-1} {
    puts $line
}
close $fp
```